# Can't use local default gateway with Cisco Anyconnect VPN connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I'm using Cisco Anyconnect as my VPN client on Windows 7. When I connect to VPN, all my traffic is routed through the remote gateway, but I'd like the traffic to route through the local gateway.

I've tried following this advice:
[OpenVPN: Only route a specific IP addresses through VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/457020/openvpn-only-route-a-specific-ip-addresses-through-vpn)

But I am not presented with any option to uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network" at Properties -> Advanced on the IPv4 settings on the VPN connection.

I'd also like to try a different VPN client, but I'm using a certificate for my VPN connection, and while Cisco Anyconnect can load this certificate (from the Windows certificate store) and then extract the host and authentication settings, I haven't found other VPN clients that can do the same with just a certificate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a split tunnel VPN on OSX for Cisco VPN client?](http://superuser.com/questions/44612/how-to-create-a-split-tunnel-vpn-on-osx-for-cisco-vpn-client). Yes I realize you're using Windows 7, but the question and answer is the same (when it comes to Cisco AnyConnect). :)  Additionally, listing alternative VPN clients woul dbe considered off-topic/not constructive.

Comment: Related: [Configuring Windows VPN Connection from Cisco AnyConnect](http://superuser.com/questions/63921/configuring-windows-vpn-connection-from-cisco-anyconnect?rq=1)